# Get Linux architecture from /proc filesystem

Tags: linux, proc, architecture

I'm writing a program in Java and I need to determine the architecture for which Linux was compiled.

I need something like `uname -m`, but without running any program, but instead from the `/proc` pseduo-fs.

What is a reliable source to read from?

Comment: Check the output of `cat /proc/version` or `cat /proc/cpuinfo`.

Comment: As for /proc/version, you can have a 64-bit cpu with a 32-bit linux installed

Comment: Why can't you use `uname -m`?

Comment: To give you a good answer we really need to know what you want to do with the information...

Comment: as an intestering tidbit getconf LONG_BIT opens libcxxx.so header to see it it is a 32 or 64 bits binary and returns accordingly 32 or 64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can have a 32-bit Linux installed in a 64-bit machine, the safer way seems to be verifying CPU capabilities. For Intel and compatible processors:

```
grep -o -w 'lm' /proc/cpuinfo
```

http://www.unixtutorial.org/2009/05/how-to-confirm-if-your-cpu-is-32bit-or-64bit/

> What you're looking for is the following flag: lm. It stands for
>   X86_FEATURE_LM, the Long Mode (64bit) support. If you can find the
>   "lm" flag among your CPU flags, this means you're looking at a 64bit
>   capable processor.

Answer (score 1):

Everything I'm seeing tells me that the `uname`binary simply makes a syscall to `uname()` to get it's information, so this may be more difficult that you want. If you're willing to implement some JNI, I'd recommend going doing so and issuing the syscall. The closest valuable pseudo file from `/proc` I can find is `/proc/sys/kernel/osrelease`, which on my system has contents of `4.2.3-300.fc23.x86_64`. This will change with versions, and may change dramatically between flavors of Linux, so it may not be as reliable as you need.

Comment: on my system `cat /proc/sys/kernel/osrelease` do not include information about architecture :) it is like this: `4.1.15-gentoo-r1-scantlight3`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is no file with line with `uname -m` output, i.e. `x86_64` or `ppc64le`. Arch is not stored in `/proc/cpuinfo` nor in files in `/proc/sys/kernel/`.

But maybe slightly better than to parse `/proc/cpuinfo` (Rui F Ribeiro's xaccepted answer) is to parse `/sys/devices/system/cpu/modalias`:

```
$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/modalias # x86_64
cpu:type:x86,ven0000fam0006mod005E:feature:,0000,0001,0002,0003...

$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/modalias # s390x
cpu:type:z13:feature:,0000,0001,0002,0003,0004,0005,0006,0007,0008,0009,000A,000B
```

But then there is a question how to map these.

BTW in kernel it's defined as `UTS_MACHINE  := $(ARCH)` in [Makefile](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.18.14/source/Makefile#L387)
and if needed adjusted by archs:

[x86{,_64}](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.18.14/source/arch/x86/Makefile):

```
ifeq ($(CONFIG_X86_32),y)
    ...
    UTS_MACHINE := i386
    ...
else
    ...
    UTS_MACHINE := x86_64
    ...
```

[powerpc: ppc{,64,64le}](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.18.14/source/arch/powerpc/Makefile):

```
UTS_MACHINE := $(subst $(space),,$(machine-y))
```

[s390x](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.18.14/source/arch/s390/Makefile):

```
UTS_MACHINE := s390x
```

[aarch64](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.18.14/source/arch/arm64/Makefile):

```
ifeq ($(CONFIG_CPU_BIG_ENDIAN), y)
...
UTS_MACHINE := aarch64_be
else
...
UTS_MACHINE := aarch64
endif
```

Answer (score -4):

Try uname command.

$ man uname

or

$ uname -a

See ya,

Comment: The OP specifically asked for something not `uname`; something reading from the `/proc` filesystem.